# Russian Character Encoding Issue w/ Chrome built-in Flash plugin on Windows

Tags: windows, flash, google-chrome, character-encoding

I'm having a weird issue with a Flash app that seems to be isolated to Google's built-in Flash plugin and Windows OS. And also, oddly, with the Russian language.

If I am running Chrome (v38) on Windows while using Chrome's built-in Flash plugin (Pepper Flash), all the Russian characters in my app show up as gibberish. If I disable the built-in Flash plugin and use Adobe's official plugin, the characters show up as normally.

Here's what the gibberish text looks like in Chrome/Windows w/ built-in Pepper Flash plugin:

[image: gibberish characters]

The Russian version of the site looks fine in IE, Firefox, and Chrome on Mac, and English, Spanish, German, and Chinese versions look fine in all browsers, including Chrome/Windows with the built-in Flash plugin.

There seems to be a related issue in the Chromium bug tracker but unfortunately it's marked as WONTFIX: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=207980

Any ideas, or am I out of luck here?

Comment: What is the default system encoding? You can check it here: http://itsecuritylab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/non_unicode_polish.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue by embedding the font in the SWF instead of relying on the system font. I guess using the system font is not always reliable if using non-standard character sets.